# Getting data from radio button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to figure out how to check and write to the console if an option in a radio form is selected.
I keep getting "Not checked", even if the right option is checked.
Any ideas?
I would prefer a solution that doesn;t include JQuery, since I study HTML and JavaScript.

Thanks!!

```
<body>
<form id="office">
    <label id="ques1"> question 1</label><br/>
        <div class="q1 wrong q1a1"><input type="radio" name="question1"    value="q1a1" /> Answer1 <br/></div>
        <div class="q1 wrong q1a2"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a2" /> Answer2 <br/></div>
        <div class="q1 wrong q1a3"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a3" /> Answer3 <br/></div>
        <div class="q1 right q1a4"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a4" /> Answer4 <br/></div>

            <br/><br/>

     <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submitAnswers" value="Submit Your Answers" onclick="checkFunction()" />


</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

 document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
if (document.querySelector('.q1 wrong q1a1').checked == true) {
  console.log('checked');
} else {
  console.log('not checked');
}
};
};
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: One of the mistake in your code was `document.querySelector('.q1 wrong q1a1')` will not be accessible, it will be like `document.querySelector('.q1.wrong.q1a1')`, But what you want exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking if the `<div>` is checked, not the radio buttons.

Change this line:

```
if (document.querySelector('.q1 wrong q1a1').checked == true) {
```

to something like:

```
if (document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name=question1]').checked == true) {
```

Comment: ...or `document.querySelector('input[name="question1"]:checked').value;`

Comment: @Pamblam Okay good point. That's probably better, if there are other `.q1a1`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers!

I tried the first option, and got "Cannot read property 'checked' of null".

When I tried  "('input[name="question1"]:checked')" I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: checkFunction is not defined"

Any other options?
Thanks

Comment: @user3185970 I just realized that one was wrong. There is no class `.q1a1` - I mistakened the `value` for `class`. Sorry. If you want to use that you're going to have to add a class to all of the radio elements. The second one is better though, especially because the radio elements are under the same name.

Comment: @user3185970 I removed the first one now. Just use that one.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: @user3185970 I'm glad I helped (don't forget to accept it please)!

Comment: @Jonathan i was just wondering how the code figures out which is the correct option (in this case- answer #1) to check? i can see it is working but i can't figure out how :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight error in the selector you are passing to the `querySelector` function.  Each classname that is in the div should be prepended with a `.`
The selector should look like this `.q1.wrong.q1a1`.  And then you can look for the input that is inside of that div as such `.q1.wrong.q1a1 input`

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
    if (document.querySelector('.q1.wrong.q1a1 input').checked == true) {
      console.log('checked');
    } else {
      console.log('not checked');
    }
  }
}
```